# ImportError: libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Raspberry Pi3

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, importerror

I have a Raspberry Pi3 and my goal is to run several python3 scripts there as a dedicated server. 
So far, I have installed with pip3 the following packages

-numpy
-pandas
-scipy
-python-Levenshtein
-fuzzywuzzy

And several other I think are not related to this case. The issue is, when I actually run my script, it gives the following error

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 305, in _custom_import
module = self._original_import(*args, **kw)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 641, in <module>
from ._ufuncs import *
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 305, in _custom_import
module = self._original_import(*args, **kw)
ImportError: libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

in the line

```
import scipy.stats as sp
```

I've googled around and so far I tried

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
```

This got me a long list of errors like `dpkg Warning: file is missing from package file list 'libdom4j-java'`

The list of missing files is quite long, it is in Spanish but you can get the gist of it by the package names

```
Seleccionando el paquete libgfortran-6-dev:armhf previamente no 
seleccionado.
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python- 
apt-common', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libnpth0:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `bind9- 
host', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libdom4j- 
java', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libenchant1c2a:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python- 
simplejson', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libjs- 
jquery', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libxaw7:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `cpp', se 
supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene 
ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `perl- 
modules-5.24', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libsbc1:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `strace', 
se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libmpeg2- 
4:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libnettle6:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python3- 
pantilthat', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python3- 
gpiozero', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libatasmart4:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libk5crypto3:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`scratch2', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libss2:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libdns162:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python- 
urllib3', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `firmware- 
realtek', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `rpi- 
chromium-mods', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libavdevice57:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libid3tag0:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `hyphen- 
en-gb', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `lp- 
solve', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`fontconfig-config', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `geany', 
se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libxcb- 
xfixes0:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libgtk2.0-common', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `lxplug- 
ptbatt', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python3- 
flask', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libmatroska6v5:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libasyncns0:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libpam- 
systemd:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libip4tc0:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libcdio13:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `piwiz', 
se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libstdc++-6-dev:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libconfig-inifiles-perl', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún 
fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`nuscratch', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libwacom- 
common', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `libjs- 
underscore', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python3- 
mote', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libaudiofile1:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python3', 
se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python- 
pianohat', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `lxplug- 
network', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `iso- 
codes', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libncursesw5:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libzbar0:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libisorelax-java', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `rename', 
se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete 
`libarchive13:armhf', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero 
actualmente instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `i2c- 
tools', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `install- 
info', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado 
dpkg: atención: falta el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python3- 
rtimulib', se supondrá que el paquete no tiene ningún fichero actualmente 
instalado
dpkg: error fatal irrecuperable, abortando:
no se puede abrir el fichero de lista de ficheros del paquete `python3- 
rpi.gpio': La estructura necesita una limpieza
sh: 1: /usr/bin/gdbus: Structure needs cleaning
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I've tried as well

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev
wget https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on- 
arm/releases/download/v1.8.0/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl
sudo pip3 install /tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
```

and `sudo apt install python3-scipy`

non of the above works and I'm stillgetting the exact same error after each try, so I'm lost here.

Answer (score 8):

Install ATLAS (presumably) ATLAS-develop from your Linux/ Raspberry Pi package manager, worked for me!

Comment: In Raspbian Buster I had to: 
```sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev;
sudo pip3 install pybind11``` to get ```pip3 install scipy``` to succeed.

Answer (score 4):

For me it worked doing the following in Raspbian Buster:

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

I used  mok0's approach:

```
sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev
sudo pip3 install pybind11
pip3 install scipy
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this on RaspberryPi zero... Be sure to install (or re-install) packages (like numpy, cython, etc.) using "sudo" or "sudo pip3"! otherwise the installed libraries are not shared.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error trying to run Numpy on a Pi Zero W. After trying various solutions including installing libatlas_base_dev separately, I switched away from using `pip3 install _____` and installed Python packages with `sudo apt install python3-_____` instead from a complete fresh start. I did not install pip at all. It fixed the problem.

Raspberry Pi intentionally maintains appropriate software through the APT and using Python's pip installer bypasses this and gives errors possibly caused by - for example - code compiled for x86 instead of ARM.