# Issues with NumPy installation

Tags: python, numpy, raspberry-pi

I am on Raspberry Pi 4.
Trying to run a script needing Pandas and Numpy.
I am getting this error for which I have not found any reference to read and attempt to solve the issue:

> We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
>
> https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
>
> Please note and check the following:
>
> - The Python version is: Python3.7 from "/usr/bin/python3"   * The
>   NumPy version is: "1.21.4"
>
> and make sure that they are the versions you expect. Please carefully
> study the documentation linked above for further help.
>
> Original error was: libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file:
> No such file or directory

Numpy is installed. I did clean up previous installations of Numpy because was giving errors with Pandas. Not sure about what to do anymore to get Numpy and Pandas correctly installed.
The last Numpy installation I did was with `python3 -m pip install numpy`

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Is: ```libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory``` the error you are getting? It is not completely clear

Comment: Also are you using a Raspberry Pi by any chance? It appears that error message was not uncommon at one point for users trying to use NumPy on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252264/importerror-libf77blas-so-3-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-di

Comment: @Capybara I have update the post. Yes it is on Raspberry

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the $PATH environment is complete? Maybe try the following:

1. Find where libf77blas is located in your setup: `find / -type f -name libf77blas*.*`
2. Add this path to your environment: `export PATH="$PATH:</path/to/libf77blas>"`

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo find / -type f -name libf77blas*.*
find: ‘/home/pi/thinclient_drives’: Permission denied
find: ‘/proc/3346/task/3346/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/3346/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
pi@raspberrypi:~ $

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, just read from some comments.
You can run these commands in conda environment and this issue will be resolved

```
pip uninstall -y numpy
pip uninstall -y setuptools
pip install setuptools
pip install numpy
```